# Make iframe/form fixed position

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe on my site wrapped in a div.

If I enter only one character in the telephone box it doesn't validate so red warning text appears.

If I then click in the email box and press tab twice, on the second tab the form shifts to the left so I can no longer see the question text.

**How can I horizontally fix the form so it doesn't move to the left?**

IFrame code:

```
<div style="border: 0px solid #a1a1a1; width: 450px; border-radius: 25px; background: #83aeff; overflow: hidden;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<iframe style="overflow: hidden;" src="https://secure.workbooks.com/process/=QzM/Workbooks_Signup_Form?edition=trial" width="490px" height="330px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe></div>
```

URL: http://content.workbooks.com/free-trial-workbooks-crm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because iframe width you've chosen is too small (I think this is due to the `Industry` select box). Just increase both `div` and `iframe` width and the shift disappears.

```
<div style="border: 0px solid #a1a1a1; width:540px; border-radius: 25px; background: #83aeff; overflow: hidden;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<iframe style="overflow: hidden;" src="https://secure.workbooks.com/process/=QzM/Workbooks_Signup_Form?edition=trial" width="500px" height="330px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe></div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rw6souyy/)

**EDIT**

To dynamically adapt iframe height, you can use this [**jquery library**](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer). Upload `iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js` script to your server and include it from iframe page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

Then upload `iframeResizer.min.js`, include it from the page with the `div` that contains `iframe` and invoke the proper function to resize iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">iFrameResize();</script>
```

This should do the trick. For more details, refer to the GitHub page linked above.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the problem but opens another one - the vertical scroll bar reappears. Is there a way of hiding it? I'm already using: `overflow: hidden;` and `scrolling="no"`.

Comment: The scrollbar appears because when an error is displayed, the total height of iframe content changes. Since the height is dynamic, you can adapt it dynamically. Just give me a couple of minutes to update my answer.

Comment: I've found a solution, but I've got a question for you: do you have permissions to change code inside iframe (or is it a third-party code that you can't modify)?

Comment: I'm really sorry Giorgio but I've never used JQuery before I have used GIT but never Github. So I don't know what I need to do.

Comment: No problem, don't worry. Click on the link I've posted and then on "Download zip". This will download a zip file on your desktop. Unzip it and go to "js" folder. Copy the scripts I've indicated and paste them in a folder where they can be accessed from the main HTML page and the iframe HTML page. Then add the snippets I've posted (don't forget to include relative path to JS files if they are not contained in the same folder of the 2 pages). Let me know.

Comment: Hi there, any news? Have you managed to upload scripts and try the code?

Comment: Hey Giorgio, I found a workaround in the end which enabled it to work. Your solution made sense so will award. Thanks for all your help.